# Wordpress index's previous post page showing same posts as index

Tags: php, wordpress

My older/newer posts links on my homepage link to page 2,3, etc... But those pages are displaying the exact same 6 posts as the homepage.
What could be causing this?
My code is as follows
from my index.php

```
<?php if (function_exists('page_navi')) { // if experimental feature is active ?>

    <?php page_navi(); // use the page navi function ?>

<?php } else { // if it is disabled, display regular wp prev & next links ?>
           <nav class="wp-prev-next">
                <div class="navigation>
                    <?php next_posts_link(_e('&laquo; Older Entries', 'bonestheme')) ?>
                    <?php previous_posts_link(_e('Newer Entries &raquo;', 'bonestheme')) ?>
                </div>
           </nav>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not use `_e()` inside `next_posts_link` or `previous_posts_link`, [**_e()**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_e) is being used to `echo` the translated result and `next_posts_link` and `previous_posts_link` takes two arguments (optional) but `_e()` not returning anything, instead it's is printing/echoing. It should be

```
<?php next_posts_link(); ?>
```

or

```
<?php next_posts_link('Older Entries »', 0); ?>
```

and same with `previous_posts_link`.

**Reference:** [**next_posts_link**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_posts_link) and [**previous_posts_link**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/previous_posts_link) and [**_e()**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_e).

Comment: That didn't change anything. It's still sending me to "/page/2/" which is displaying the same posts as index.